# Error writting a txt file String index out of range

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter, writer

Can someone explain me why I get: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    Date date;
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try { writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));        
            writer.write(" ",0,1);
            writer.write("FICH", 1, 4);
            writer.write("1234", 5, 4);
            writer.close();
        System.err.println(writer.toString());
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FicheroTdALogic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    finally {
           try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BufferedWriter.write()` takes a string, offset and length. Offset tells the first character to write, length tells the count (how many).

Character indices are 0-based. The first character has an index of `0`, the 2nd has an index of `1` etc.

So obviously in a string of `"FICH"` is 4 characters, valid indices are `0..3` inclusive. offset = 1 and length = 4 results in the last char being 5 which is out of bounds (illegal character index).

Similarly `"1234"` has valid indices `0..3` inclusive, even the offset is out of bounds (5) and also the last char (which would be at 9).

If you just want to write a whole `String`, don't pass anything else:

```
writer.write("Whole string will be written.");
```

If you need just a part of it, properly specify offset and length:

```
writer.write("Hello", 1, 3); // Writes "ell"
```